# Aptana Studio, writing Ruby: Auto completion not complete

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, aptana

I'm currently looking into Ruby for a project. I've downloaded and installed Aptana Studio 3.3.2.20130281546 separately from my Eclipse installation (not as plugin).

I'm using [why's (poignant) guide to ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) and have reached [chapter 4](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-4.html). I'm looking at arrays and hashes, especially hashes inside of arrays. I'm at this code example:

```
kitty_toys = [
  {:shape => 'sock', :fabric => 'cashmere'},
  {:shape => 'mouse', :fabric => 'calico'},
  {:shape => 'eggroll', :fabric => 'chenille'}
]

kitty_toys.sort_by { |toy| toy[:shape] }.each do |toy|
  puts "Blixy has a #{ toy[:shape] } made of #{ toy[:fabric] }"
end
```

Now, for exploring ruby methods, auto completion is a very useful tool. However, it doesn't seem to work as I'd expect it. The sorting above isn't auto completed by Aptana. Trying to reproduce the sort, I did

```
kitty_toys.
```

However, what the auto completion offers then doesn't show the used method sort_by. The listed methods are:

```
abbrev
dclone
pretty_print
pretty_print_cycle
quote
shelljoin
to_csv
```

Is there something wrong with the code? It doesn't seem to be a problem of the position. Trying the auto complete before the sorting doesn't show anything different.

Thank you.